Standalone iMessage app doesn't appear in neither simulator nor device after installation
I created a standalone iMessage app using Xcode template as the below:

I didn't change a single line of code except just populating all necessary icons. After installing the extension using Xcode, nothing showed up in the iMessage. Did I miss anything?


I tried the to recreate the same problem but it is running without any issue . Have you checked the minimum deployment target for the app ?
It works with Xcode 15.2.

What's the version of your Xcode and simulator? Mine is Xcode 15.3 and iPhone 15 (17.2). The minimum deployment target is correct, but it still doesn't work.

My Xcode version is 15.2  and the minimum deployment I have for project is 17.2 (simulator is same) Can you try to run it Xcode 15.2 , as I have seen a lot of people having issues with Xcode 15.3 @appthumb

This appears to be more of a question (or a request for clarification) than an answer. Please try to save the answer space for answers that recognise the problem as valid, and proffer a solution for it.

@Kshitij876 You are right. I am able to install the standalone iMessage app to simulator using Xcode 15.2. It must be a bug of Xcode 15.3.

@halfer I agree but because I was not able to comment on the questions because of my reputation was not 50 plus I had to put it as an answer. Now I can comment as well as my reputation is increased.

@appthumb glad I could be of help. Happy coding.

Seems to still be a problem in Xcode 15.4. I glanced at the logs, but could not find a  clear point of failure.

Does seem to be working in Xcode 16 now!
